# removing points while keeping the line in a scatter plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I remove the points from a scatter plot created by below code ? I just wanted to keep the smoothed line.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg, color=cyl, shape=cyl)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method=lm)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take out `geom_point`, it's what's generating the points.

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg, color = cyl)) +
  geom_smooth(method = lm)
```

[image]

Created on 2018-04-26 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).